# Q: OAuth2 for Imgur giving me over capacity status 500 error

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, authorization, imgur

I am trying to follow a tutorial for an image upload application For Vue.js however I am unable to authenticate with OAuth2 for Imgur. I am following exactly what the imgur API docs instructions are on how to implement it so I'm pretty sure my code is correct.

The **response** I'm getting after I get forwarded to https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=token&state=imagestorage and I click **allow** application is below: (FOR THIS EXAMPLE I DID REMOVE MY CLIENT_ID)

```
{"data":{"error":"Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later."},"success":false,"status":500}
```

The response I am supposed to get back is a redirect URL callback with the access_token `http://example.com#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`. However instead of getting that I get the error.

I know what status 500 is and I know it means it's a server error and there is nothing I can do on my end and its on Imgur's side.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and how was it resolved?

Comment: Same problem here. But for now, I got status 403 instead, and sometimes it response normally. Try to Google it and found many cases as we encounter in the last 3 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know what status 500 is and I know it means it's a server error and there is nothing I can do on my end and its on Imgur's side.

You are completely right here. We unfortunately experienced a bug on our side that was to blame. The good news however is that the bug has since been resolved!

Going to `https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=<resp_type>&state=<string>` should now redirect you to the consent page, followed by callback URL configured for the application with `access_token`, `expires_in` (and others) in query strings as described in the [documentation](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#authorization-and-oauth).